# Firefox won't wrap table, but other browers do

Tags: php, html

My page builds the string $BookBody and then echos it in the table of my html. What is supposed to appear on the screen is a list of book covers with their price below. After 5 results the next result is pushed to a new line in Chrome, Explorer, and Safari, but Firefox won't wrap.

```
$BookBody .= '<table width="10%" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                   <td width="100" height="163">
                      <a href="index.php?pid=' . $tom . '">
                        <img src="' . $coverimage . '" height="151" width="100"
                      </a>
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="100" height="16" align="center" valign="middle"                 
                       bgcolor="#590000" >' . $bookprice 
                  .'</td>
                </tr>
              </table>';

---------------------------------------------------------------

<body>

<table width="800" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="8">
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top"><?php echo $BookBody ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: You should close your `<img>` tag.  Does that correct the situation?

Comment: Sadly, no. Closing the image tag does not fix the issue.

Comment: Another issue that may be causing you issues:  you are calling out width, height, alignment all with deprecated methods.  You should, for example call out in the image: `<img src="'.$coverimage.'" style="height:151px;width:100px;" />`.  Please check the lastest CSS standards.  Firefox is very standards compliant.

Comment: Thanks so much, but it still doesn't work. I wonder if it may be because I'm creating a table that is then put into a table.

Comment: It works when I don't use the table, and just use the html image link, but I want to have the book price underneath the books.

Comment: You shouldn't use a table for layout; tables are really only for tabular data.  Ideally, you should have the image in a `<div>`, with a `<div>` containing the book price underneath.  Check out :http://webdesign.about.com/od/layout/a/aa111102a.htm, especially "Tables for Layout are Invalid in HTML 4.01".  Trust me, we all had to make the move to CSS, but in the end you will like it better.